# Prove that $\langle \{a+b\sqrt[3]2 \mid a, b \in \mathbb{Q}\}, +, \cdot \rangle$ is not a field

Tags: real-analysis, field-theory

I got this question in my real analysis course:

> Prove that $\langle \{a+b\sqrt{2} \mid a, b \in \mathbb{Q}\}, +, \cdot \rangle$ is a field, but $\langle \{a+b\sqrt[3]{2} \mid a, b \in \mathbb{Q}\}, +, \cdot \rangle$ is not.

Obviously, I checked for the field properties (closure, commutativity, associativity, identity, inverse and distributivity) and they all check out except for the inverse. The additive inverse is trivial in both cases, and in the first case I found that the following is an inverse of $a+b\sqrt{2}$:

$$\frac{a}{a^2-2b^2}+\frac{-b}{a^2-2b^2}\sqrt{2}$$

$\forall$ $a, b \in \mathbb{Q}$. I have not been able to reproduce a similar result for the second set, which leads me to believe that a proof that the inverse does not always exist is the crux of the argument.

Any hints on how I can go about proving this?

---

**Note:** I have not had a course on abstract/modern algebra yet, so I only know the definition of a field and not any properties it may possess.

Comment: Can you prove $  \{a+b\sqrt[3]2 \mid a, b \in \mathbb{Q}\} $ does not contain $(\sqrt[3]2)^2$?

Comment: For the second one, check again closure of multiplication. What about $(\sqrt[3]{2})^2$=

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Ah, thanks, I'm not sure how this slipped my mind.

Comment: Now that I think about it, it doesn't seem that easy to me to show that $(\sqrt[3]{2})^2$ is actually not an element of the second set. Of course if one knows basic stuff about field extensions then it is easy since the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt[3]{2}$ over $\Bbb Q$ has degree $3$. But without that that I don't know...

Comment: Can you observe that $x^3-2$ has no rational root and hence it is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q} $?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $2^{2/3} = a+b2^{1/3}$ then $2^{1/3}$ is a root of $X^2-bX-a$ which means that $2^{1/3} = \frac{b\pm \sqrt{b^2+4a}}{2}$ an obvious contradiction.

(if you prefer then $X^3-2\in \Bbb{Q}[x]$ is irreducible so $2^{1/3}$ can't be the root of a degree two polynomial in $\Bbb{Q}[x]$)

Comment: By e.g. Eisenstein's criterion.

Comment: Or in $\Bbb{F}_7[x]$

Answer (score 3):

As [J.W. Tanner](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/615567/j-w-tanner) and [leoli1](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/649658/leoli1) mentioned in their comments, the second set does not satisfy the *closure* property due to $(\sqrt[3]{2})^2$ not being an element. Hence it is not a field and we are done.

Comment: On the other hand, the set of all $ a + b 2^{1/3} + c 4^{1/3}$ for rational $a,b,c$ does become a field; there is a thing called a norm form involved, this one is $a^3 + 2 b^3 + 4 c^3 - 6 abc$  which is in the denominator when looking for the multiplicative inverse of an element